# Is it possible to only fill in 50% of the missing values in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is the DF:

```
amount    cost
5         NaN
7         NaN
9         78.0
6         80.0
12        NaN
14        NaN
```

And I only want to fill 50% of the NANs so that I would get something like this:

```
amount    cost
5        'hello'
7         NaN
9         78.0
6         80.0
12        NaN
14       'hello'
```

And is it possible to fill lets say 28% of the missing data with bigger dataSets.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
idx=df.index[df.cost.isna()]
df.loc[np.random.choice(idx, size=int(len(idx)/2) ,replace=False),'cost']='somevalue'
df
Out[16]: 
   amount       cost
0       5        NaN
1       7  somevalue
2       9         78
3       6         80
4      12  somevalue
5      14        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [df.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
nans = df.loc[df.cost.isna(), ]
nans.iloc[:int(len(nans) * 0.5), 'cost'] = 'hello'
df.update(nans.cost)
```